# Use JavaScript includes function or any good alternate instead of endsWith in given function

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have following function that checks if url ends with any of the values in array instead I want to check if url contains any of the value in array.
If url **contain** any value in array function should return true else false.

```
var hasUrlCacheExcludeMatch = function(url) {
    var cacheExcludeUrls = [
        '/u/register',
        '/i/new',
        '/login'
    ];

    return cacheExcludeUrls.some(path => url.endsWith(path));
}
```

Let me clear, I want to check if any value in array is substring of url.

Comment: I believe replacing `.endsWith()` with `.includes()` would work

Comment: @NickParsons It won't work in any cases : 'foo/u/register/failure' will also match

Comment: That's the point @Bertrand. The OP _wants_ it to match.

Comment: Better read better. My bad

Comment: Let me clear, I want to check if any value in array is substring of url.